# Floating DIVS - One Overlapping for no Reason?

Tags: css, html, floating

...and by 'no reason' I mean; for a reason I'm clearly (and likely blatently) overlooking. This is such a NOOB question - but I for the life of me can't figure out what's going wrong with my floating divs.

As seen here: http://codysilfies.com/kenji/beta.html

I've got a Container div (#Wrapper), which houses a few divs - among them a content area (#content) which has a menu (#menu) that floats left; and a div to house text (which doesn't have an ID just yet).

I THOUGHT that aligning them both left would have the two divs sit right against each other; but it's not working that way.  The box with text overlaps the menu messing with the layout.  I also have to place the text PRIOR to the menu in the code; or else it'll show up below the main menu (which shouldn't be normal behavior - it should sit against the other div!

I know I can set a width and float the text RIGHT - but it's been requested that the page resize with the browser page.

I know it's something stupid and simple that I'm overlooking...but I can't see it. Any help would be hot! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Weird. It works fine when I click it!  I guess try:  http://www.codysilfies.com/kenji/beta.html

Answer (score 0):

HI now give to the `margin-left:190px;` in your `float right` **div**

as like this

```
<div style="float:right;margin-left:190px;">
```

result is

**[*this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65w9I.png)**

Comment: Right - but then the text content is still pushing the menu content down below the div (the menu should be maybe half the size it is - if that).  Ideally the menu would sit right next to the text, and be only the height of those two menu items.

If you do:  <div style="float:left;">1</div> and <div style="float:left;">2</div> - those two divs sit right next to each other.  Why don't mine act the same way?

Answer (score 0):

also, remember the box model. It's generally a good idea to give a width to a floated element when it's more structure related, as this is, versus just an image. That will also help side-step issues in IE 7 and 8.

Comment: The menu does have a fixed width - the only reason the other one does not is because I need the content to be able to expand/collapse if a user sizes or resizes their window.  Setting a width to it kind of prevents that - and it doesn't solve the overlap problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was just me being dumb.  I forgot to add a float to the menu.  D'oh!